# Formatting JSON data and displaying in a PHP for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have some form data which I'm saving in JSON format using jQuery (this is all working fine).

But I then want to take the JSON data and display it in a PHP for loop. This is where I'm having trouble as jQuery's serializeArray and JSON.stringify just adds each form value in one bit chunk e.g.

```
check in, check out, room, adults, children, check in, check out, room, adults, children, check in, check out, room, adults, children
```

But I want to separate each room e.g.

```
(Room 1) check in, check out, room, adults, children
(Room 2) check in, check out, room, adults, children
(Room 3) check in, check out, room, adults, children
```

JSFiddle of how the form data is created (everything working fine): https://jsfiddle.net/kuohhm2q/

PHP I'm using to try a display JSON data in for loop (not working):

```
<?php 

$json_data = '[{"name":"check_in","value":"07/11/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/26/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_1"},{"name":"adults","value":"2"},{"name":"children","value":"3"},{"name":"check_in","value":"07/27/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/29/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_2"},{"name":"adults","value":"3"},{"name":"children","value":"2"}]';

$data = json_decode($json_data, true); 

//print_r($data);

foreach($data as $key => $val) { ?>

    <?php echo $key; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you can't modify how you get that data from the database, then you can `array_chunk()` the decoded JSON at an interval of `4` to create your desired sub-arrays. (***Remember:*** *This is heavily dependent on the fact that the data is presented in groups of 4*)

Comment: `echo $key` will not give u the data you want but numerical array indexes

Comment: I can modify the format of the JSON data in jQuery if nessessary - would it be better to do this, or array_chunk() the decoded JSON at an interval of 4?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$data as $key` and `echo $key['name']`

```
 <?php 

$json_data = '[{"name":"check_in","value":"07/11/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/26/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_1"},{"name":"adults","value":"2"},{"name":"children","value":"3"},{"name":"check_in","value":"07/27/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/29/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_2"},{"name":"adults","value":"3"},{"name":"children","value":"2"}]';

$data = json_decode($json_data, true); 
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($data);
$i=0;
foreach($data as $key) {
  if($i==2) break;
 echo 'Name: '.$key['name'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo 'Value: '.$key['value'];
 echo "<br>";
$i++;
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: I understand that, but at the moment it's displaying 10 values for $key (because there are 10 bits of data saved) but I only want to display 2 $keys, 1 for each saved form, if that makes sense?

Comment: i used simple logic.. run loop 2 times and then i break the loop.. i think you need this type of code.. any update?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you're building the JSON. Each item has it's own object due to the use of `serializeArray()` on the form, which means you have no idea what property is for what room.

To fix this use `map()` to build the array of objects *per room*. Like this:

```
function save_all_rooms() {
  $(".save_all_rooms").on('click', function(e) {
    var formData = $('.add_new_form .the_form').map(function() {
      return {
        check_in: $(this).find('[name="check_in"]').val(),
        check_out: $(this).find('[name="check_out"]').val(),
        room_type: $(this).find('[name="room_type"]').val(),
        adults: $(this).find('[name="adults"]').val(),
        children: $(this).find('[name="children"]').val()          
      }
    }).get();
    console.log(formData);
  });
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kuohhm2q/3/)

The result of this will be in the below format, where each object contains the properties of a room. This can then be easily iterated over:

```
[{
  "check_in": "07/04/2017",
  "check_out": "07/10/2017",
  "room_type": "option_1",
  "adults": "1",
  "children": "1"
}, {
  "check_in": "07/28/2017",
  "check_out": "07/31/2017",
  "room_type": "option_3",
  "adults": "3",
  "children": "3"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
<?php 

$json_data = '[{"name":"check_in","value":"07/11/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/26/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_1"},{"name":"adults","value":"2"},{"name":"children","value":"3"},{"name":"check_in","value":"07/27/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/29/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_2"},{"name":"adults","value":"3"},{"name":"children","value":"2"}]';

$data = json_decode($json_data, true); 

//print_r($data);

foreach($data as $key => $val) {
foreach($val as $val_key=>$val_val) {
    echo $val_key.":".$val_val."</br>";
}
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to read the json value and you can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to keep the first two elements.Try this one:

```
<?php 

$json_data = '[{"name":"check_in","value":"07/11/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/26/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_1"},{"name":"adults","value":"2"},{"name":"children","value":"3"},{"name":"check_in","value":"07/27/2017"},{"name":"check_out","value":"07/29/2017"},{"name":"room_type","value":"option_2"},{"name":"adults","value":"3"},{"name":"children","value":"2"}]';

$data = json_decode($json_data); 

foreach(array_slice($data,0,2) as $key => $val) {

 echo $val->name."-".$val->value."<br>";

} ?>
```

[check the Output here](https://3v4l.org/W6FlG)

Comment: This is what you are expecting? @The Bobster